# Java logic not able to read formula based cell in excel

Tags: java, excel-formula

This is method for reading excel:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void readFromExcel(String file) throws IOException {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        evaluator.evaluateAll();
        XSSFSheet myExcelSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(2);
        Iterator<Row> itr = myExcelSheet.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Row row = itr.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                    System.out.print("formula:" + cell.getCellFormula() + "\t\t\t");
                    String value = evaluator.evaluate(cell).getStringValue();
                    System.out.print(value + "\t\t\t");
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC: // field that represents
                                                    // numeric cell type
                    // getting the value of the cell as a number
                    System.out.print(cell.getDateCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                    break;
                case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING: // field that represents string
                                                // cell type
                    // getting the value of the cell as a string
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t\t");
                    break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

I'm getting below output:

**Date          ME          Balance

formula:'Tab1'!C1           null            formula:EOMONTH(A2,0)           null            formula:'Tab1'!$D$3*1000            null**

it's reading formula of the cell but not value.I have tried all methods for FormulaEvaluator. Can anyone please assist on this? I have attached the sample sheet image.[SampleScenario.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD5DR.png) [Tab1.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpwDi.png) [Tab2.xlsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMVHP.png)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what `Tab1` looks like?

Comment: @jdaz I have added the screenshots for both the tabs.

Comment: Can anybody please assist on this?